# issue with alignment with two objects

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment

I'm trying to make puzzle piece, so I want to cut out circle from rectangle, but somehow I can't make their left sides to coincide :/ 
Does anyone had same problem?

[image]

As you see when I click 'Horizontal Align Left' icon, it's what I get on pic.

Comment: Turn off Align to Pixel Grid maybe???

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you could have one of the Snap to... toggled on.

View > Snap To Grid
View > Snap To Point
View > Perspective Grid > Snap To Grid

[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, but none of them helped - nothing changed

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili sorry I can't think of any other way to fix it. Maybe the best this to do is to use the Pathfinder tools to create what you are trying to do without having to use align.

Answer (score 1):

Check that one or both of your shapes aren't aligning to the **Pixel Grid**.

- Select your shapes
- Open the Transform palette
- Make sure **Align to Pixel Grid** is unticked.

When working on small shapes at a high zoom level, I sometimes find this can cause shapes to shift or warp slightly.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using the Align Objects tool, it's not the outline/path of the object that gets aligned but instead it's the bounding box.  Make sure your bounding box isn't extending beyond the edge of the circle, for some reason.  See if your bounding box is turned on by going to the View menu and choosing "View Bounding Box".

If your bounding box is out of sorts, you can reset it by clicking on the Edit menu and choosing "Transform" -> "Reset Bounding Box".